# How do I enable wobbly windows?

Tags: compiz

Just a short question, I made a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and I have installed CompizConfig Settings Manager and ubuntu-restricted-extras, but I am still unable to enable wobbly windows. What do I need to enable it?

Comment: Install `compiz-plugins` package

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To enable wobbly windows, after you have installed [**CompizConfig Settings Manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), you have to install [**compiz-plugins**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins/), and then enable **Wobbly Windows** plugin from CompizConfig Settings Manager:

[image: Enable Wobbly Windows]

Answer (score 5):

You will also need to install compiz plugins. Run the following command -

`sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`

You should then see Wobbly Windows option in CompizConfig Settings Manager.