# How do I enable wobbly windows in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: window, animations

do you know how to enable wobbly windows in Ubuntu 20.04LTS ?
i was trying to do that

Comment: An **old** answer, but have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/449704/212930)?

Comment: This old answer is probably no use because it is based on the assumption that Compiz is being used which was true for former version of Ubuntu but which isn't in use anymore on the 20.04.  I fear, to enable wobbly windows (and other Compiz fancinesses) one would need to replace the window manager (default is Gnome) by Compiz.  And there is a reason they moved away from Compiz which is AFAIK its lower reliability compared to Gnome.

Comment: I think Compiz can work with Gnome Desktop rather than being a replacement for it. But I failed getting the animation effects after configuring them in the Compiz Config application, on my specific box. It's hard for me to trace what breaks the integration.

Answer (score 1):

Install this **Gnome** extension **[Compiz alike windows effect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2950/compiz-alike-windows-effect/)**

But first install **GNOME Shell integration** for your browser [**Google Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en), [**Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) You can also use **Chrome extension** for **MS Edge** and **Opera** browser, after that click on the off button to install the extension

Also you can change settings, update, remove the extension form the same link **[Compiz alike windows effect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2950/compiz-alike-windows-effect/)**